# Modeling database with EF, having cycle inside database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm having problem with modelling my database.
I'm using EF 6 on mvc.net

I have three tables. `Project`, `Person`, `Task`.
Every `Person` has a `Task` and a `Project`.

These are my classes:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TestTask> Tasks  { get; set; }

}

public class TestTask
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }  
}
```

The problem started when I decided that each project needs its own tasks, and also the other way around, I want each task to have a projectId, so I can get all the tasks for the project (tasks with and without related `Person`).

If I add a task list inside project and a projectId inside tasks, I get an error from entity framework. If I just have a projectId inside the task class (without any navigation properties inside project), this field is not used by ef.

I'm interested in having the following methods:

1. `GetTasksForProject(int id)` - this will get the project id and return all tasks related to this project, either a task which is related to a project with no person, or a task which is related to the project through a person working in this project.
2. `GetTasksOnlyForProject` - this will return tasks which related to the project but unrelated to any person in this project
3. `GetTasksForPerson` - this will return tasks which are related to given person

What do you suggest? I pretty new to EF and MVC.net but not to programming and to sql. Probably making the database first would be easier (for now) but I want to learn the code first approach.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: a great way to learn can be to create the database first, then 'Reverse Engineer' it: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/data-driver/2014/03/entity-frameworkupdate.aspx Then you can review the code that's produced and see how it lines up with the database you created, and start to make any new changes in the code-first model.

Comment: @DrewJordan that's a great idea, I will look this way, Thanks!